# How to use ODBC adapter to retrieve data from Access db?

Tags: c#, ms-access, odbc

I am having problem with my `OdbcDataReader` in C#. When I am trying to retrieve data from my MS Access database, I have a class with my connection details.

This is my code:

```
string datefrom =  dateFrom.Value.Date.ToShortDateString() ;
string dateto =  dateTo.Value.Date.ToShortDateString() ;
query = "SELECT date_received,item_details,quantity FROM tbl_stock WHERE date_received between "+ datefrom +" and "+ dateto +"";

OdbcDataReader dr = execmd.selectDataReader(query);

while (dr.Read())
{
    string rdate = dr[0].ToString();
    string item = dr[1].ToString();
    string quantity = dr[2].ToString();

    query1 = "insert into tmp_tbl_stock values('"+ rdate +"','"+ item +"','"+ quantity +"')";
    execmd.executeCmd_Sql(query1);
}
```

The ODBC is not retrieving any data while my Access database has some rows between this date range.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably your dates are not interpreted correctly by the ODBC provider. You should use a parameterized query where you have the possibility to specify the parameter type without resorting to a string concatenation

Comment: Thanx Steve, But I am actually a bit weak in parametrized query will u help me regarding this.......

Comment: Yes, but you need to change the code of selectDataReader. Could you show that code? (Also the executeCmd need to be changedm but that will be easy then)

Comment: A date in MS Access is delimited with hash (#), not apostrophe ('). A parameter is a much better idea. It is best to format dates to year, month, day.

Comment: Remou, with hash(#) its work fine. Should I go for parametrized or hash(#)

Answer (score 0):

Jet normally expects dates in the format #mm/dd/yyyy#, so that is likely to cause your problem. It might be that the ODBC driver does something with dates though.